# embeddings layer produce cannot be interpreted as a Tensor in sagemaker?

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use python SDk with tensorflow for test classification on sagemaker. I am able to modify this https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_abalone_age_predictor_using_keras/abalone.py and run it but when I  change the arch to include embeddings layer, I get the error

> "Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("first-layer/embeddings:0", shape=(*, *), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph."*

When I run it as a standalone model, it runs perfectly. 
here is arch for standalone model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                        EMBEDDING_DIM,
                        weights=[embedding_matrix],
                        input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                        trainable=False))

model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=10, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=15, padding='same', activation='selu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=15, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=25, padding='same', activation='softmax'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=15, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

Here is my model_fn for sagemaker:

```
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False, name='first-layer')(features[INPUT_TENSOR_NAME])

first = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=10, padding='same', activation='relu')(embedding)
second = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=15, padding='same', activation='relu')(first)
 third = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=15, padding='same', activation='relu')(second)
 fourth = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=25, padding='same', activation='softmax')(third)
 fifth = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=15, padding='same', activation='relu')(fourth)
sixth = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(fifth)

output = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(sixth)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))(output)
```

There no issue with input dimension or value, if I replace this arch with a simple arch of dense layer only, code works perfectly.

I have already tried solution on 
[TensorFlow: The tensor is not the element of this graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219094/tensorflow-the-tensor-is-not-the-element-of-this-graph) but I get a new error

> Input graph and Layer graph are not the same: Tensor("random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:1", shape=(128, 200), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0) is not from the passed-in graph.*

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?